# ASP .NET create other Session when switch to http://example.com or http://www.example.com

Tags: asp.net, cookies, session, cross-domain

If I type `http://example.com` and login to my site and close my browser, re-open it and retype `http://example.com` then I am logged in.

However, when I type `http://example.com`, login, close the browser, re-open it, type **`http://www.example.com`** then I am NOT logged in.

I do not use ASP .NET authentication classes. 
I run IIS 6 with both `example.com` and `www.example.com` URLs added to "Multiple identities for this web site" in IIS.

I do not wish the current behavior. Are there other things that can be affected because of this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure from your domain panel that it is referring to same IP Address and code.
I was having same issue and found that IP Address was different.

Comment: Name   Type   Data,
   A  89.38.215.221,
cp  A  89.38.214.101,
ftp  A  89.38.214.141,
mail  A  89.38.209.22,
www  A  89.38.215.221,
MX  [10], mail.cupacupelor.ro,
NS  ns1.livehosting.info,
NS  ns2.livehosting.info,
TXT  v=spf1 a mx -all

I have these

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't share cookies between example.com and www.example.com, due to a quirk in the [cookie specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt).

Instead, what you should do is pick one of the domains as your primary. Then, detect references to the other domain, and redirect users from there back to the primary. For example, you could choose www.example.com as the primary, and redirect references to example.com back to www.example.com.

That way, the authentication cookies will be present if the user tries to switch from one domain to another.

Comment: public static void AddForFirstTime(string nickname, string guid)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(LoginCookie.CookieName);        
        cookie.Values["nickname"] = nickname;
        cookie.Values["guid"] = guid;
        cookie.Values["action"] = "login";
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
this is all what I do with cookies